# must use 'class' tag to refer to type ... / expected a type specifier errors (C++ chess)

Tags: c++, types, constructor, chess

Several things are wrong with this function, and I can't work out what.

Here is the main function:

```
void ChessBoard::resetBoard(){
// set start-of-game parameters
  gameEnd = false;
  turn = White;
  capturedPiece = NULL;


  // set initial positions to NULL by default
  for (map<string, Piece*>::iterator it = Board.begin(); it != Board.end(); it++) {
        it->second = NULL;
        }

  // add white pieces in their initial positions
  Board["A1"] = new Rook(White, this);
  Board["B1"] = new Knight(White, this);
  Board["C1"] = new Bishop(White, this);
  Board["D1"] = new Queen(White, this);
  Board["E1"] = new King(White, this);
  Board["F1"] = new Bishop(White, this);
  Board["G1"] = new Knight(White, this);
  Board["H1"] = new Rook(White, this);
  const string wfile = "ABCDEFGH";
  for (char const &c: wfile) {
    string notation = file + "2";
    Board[notation] = new Pawn(White, this);
    }
  // add black pieces in their initial positions
  Board["A8"] = new Rook(Black, this);
  Board["B8"] = new Knight(Black, this);
  Board["C8"] = new Bishop(Black, this);
  Board["D8"] = new Queen(Black, this);
  Board["E8"] = new King(Black, this);
  Board["F8"] = new Bishop(Black, this);
  Board["G8"] = new Knight(Black, this);
  Board["H8"] = new Rook(Black, this);
  const string bfile = "ABCDEFGH";
  for (char const &c: bfile) {
  string notation2 = bfile + "2";
  Board[notation2] = new Pawn(Black, this);
}

}
```

Here is my class definition for Piece:

```
#ifndef PIECE_H
#define PIECE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum Colour {White, Black};
enum Type {King, Queen, Rook, Knight, Bishop, Pawn};

class ChessBoard; 
class Piece {
public:
  Piece(Colour colour, ChessBoard *board);
  virtual ~Piece();
  Colour getColour();
  Type getType();
  void printColour();
  void printType();
  virtual bool validMove(const string source, const string dest);
  bool freeRow(const string source, const string dest);
  bool freeColumn(const string source, const string dest);
  bool freeDiagonal(const string source, const string dest);


protected:
  ChessBoard *board;
  Colour colour;
  Type type;

};

#endif
```

and relevant parts of its implementation file:

```
#include "ChessBoard.h"
#include "Piece.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Piece::Piece(Colour colour, ChessBoard *board)
  : colour(colour), board(board){}

Piece::~Piece(){}

Colour Piece::getColour(){
  return colour;
}

Type Piece::getType(){
  return type;
}

void Piece::printType(){
  switch(type){
    case King:
      cout << "King";
      break;
    case Queen:
      cout << "Queen";
      break;
    case Rook:
      cout << "Rook";
      break;
    case Knight:
      cout << "Knight";
      break;
    case Bishop:
      cout << "Bishop";
      break;
    case Pawn:
      cout << "Pawn";
      break;
  }
}

void Piece::printColour(){
  switch(colour){
    case White:
      cout << "White";
      break;
    case Black:
      cout << "Black";
      break;
  }
}
```

And here is a representative class implementation for a particular chess piece (they're all almost identical):

```
#include "Knight.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Knight::Knight(Colour colour, ChessBoard* board)
  : Piece(colour, board){

  type = Type::Knight;
}

Knight::~Knight(){}

bool Knight::validMove(const string source, const string dest){
  if((abs(dest[0] - source[0]) == 2) && (abs(dest[1] - source[1]) == 1))
    return true;

  if((abs(dest[0] - source[0]) == 1) && (abs(dest[1] - source[1]) == 2))
    return true;

  return false;

}
```

I've tried writing Knight::Knight etc. to distinguish the derived piece classes from the piece types in the enum, but that didn't work. Is there something wrong with my constructors? And while I'm at it, is there something wrong with the way I iterated through letters to place pawns?

(I also definitely have included all the header files!)

Comment: use a scoped enum https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: I'm not trying to invoke the enum Types here though, I'm trying to invoke the derived classes of Piece corresponding to each piece? How do I do that?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need all those parentheses in the piece validation code. `if (abs(dest[0] - source[0] == 2 && abs(dest[1] - source[1]) == 1)` is sufficient and much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that while your intention is to invoke the derived `Piece` classes, the names of the classes are hidden by the attributes that you have defined in the enum. That is, the class `Rook` is hidden by the enum attribute `Rook`. It then wants you to write:

```
Board["A1"] = new class Rook(White, this);
```

Making you specify that you are talking about the class.

The scoped enum mentioned in the comments of your question is the way to go to fix the issue. Changing:

```
enum Type {King, Queen, Rook, Knight, Bishop, Pawn};
```

to

```
enum class Type {King, Queen, Rook, Knight, Bishop, Pawn};
```

resolves the issue.